# How to add functions IF to cells when exporting using blade view laravel

Tags: laravel

I want add function if to cells when exporting using blade view laravel. but not working, but when i add function sum, it work. this my code

at view

```
<td>=if(A1<50,"B",A1<=100,"A","E")</td> -->Not working
<td>=sum(A1:A8)</td> --Work
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to export this to Microsoft Excel.

If you want to display "A" for *A1 cell* values less than 50, "B" for values less or equal 100 and "E" for values greater than 100 then I think the following should work:

`=if(A1<50,"B", if(A1<=100, "A", "E"))`